pyvista export does not preserve multiline texts
I am rendering a mesh with Pyvista (version 0.43.5) and I have a problem with multiline texts at export.
In the interactive window and when I take a screenshot, a multiline title (or any other multiline text) is rendered well. But when I export to svg, the multiline is gone:



interactive window and screenshot (OK)
export to svg (via plotter.save_graphic) (KO)









Here is the code I use:
import pyvista as pv
mesh = pv.Cylinder()
pl = pv.Plotter(off_screen=True)
pl.add_mesh(mesh, label="cyl")
pl.add_title("first line\nsecond line\nthird one")
pl.save_graphic('multiline_title_test.svg')  # 'svg', 'eps', 'ps', 'pdf', 'tex'
pl.show(screenshot='multiline_title_test.png')
pl.close()

Question: is there a way to preserve multiline at svg export? (using pyvista or maybe vtk)
Edit 1:  as I advance in understanding of the problem (but not of the solution so far):
The generated svg page includes for text:
<text fill="#000000" x="512" y="-5" font-size="45" text-anchor="middle" dy="45" font-family="Helvetica">
first line
second line
third one</text>

From this link How to display multiple lines of text in SVG?, I understand it should include some 'tspan' with x and dy properties. Is this the only way?

This looks like it's a bug, or at worst a feature request for PyVista. Please consider opening a bug report.

@AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїніn, you are right, so I did it here https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/issues/6328

My current workaround (as I did not try to modify svg after generation) is to pass multiple texts instead of one and positioning them from top left corner in pixel system:
import pyvista as pv
mesh = pv.Cylinder()
pl = pv.Plotter(off_screen=False)
pl.add_mesh(mesh, label="cyl")

# parameters:
title = "first line\nsecond line\nthird one"
font_size = 18

title_bits = title.split("\n")
window_size = pl.window_size  # [1024, 768]
for ii, tb in enumerate(title_bits):
    # position when specified as a tuple is in pixel coordinate system (x, y) ie from lower left corner
    # from top left corner we decrease y. Warning first line bottom shall not be at top of figure (hence the ii = 1.5)!
    # default font is 18
    position=(10, window_size[1] - (ii + 1.5) * font_size * 2)  
    pl.add_text(text=tb,
                font_size=font_size,  # default is 18
                position=position,  # pixel coordinate system (x, y) from lower left corner
    )
pl.save_graphic('multiline_title_test.svg')  # 'svg', 'eps', 'ps', 'pdf', 'tex'
pl.show(screenshot='multiline_title_test.png')
pl.close()

It works as expected for the export svg :-) with no problem when changing window size.
However there is a big downside: in the interactive window, when I rescale, text may go out of window as its position is no more dynamically calculated...
